# Running a process in the background as part of a longer script

Tags: bash

Given the following bash script, I would like the second step (the http-server invocation) to be run in the background.

The following appears to create a background process before the grunt call completes successfully, which is unexpected.

```
grunt build && http-server ./dist/artifacts -p 11111 &
```

I want the grunt step to run to successful completion, and then for the http-server call to be made with it running in the background.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{ }` around the part that you would like to be backgrounded:

```
grunt build && { http-server ./dist/artifacts -p 11111 & }
```

The curly braces create a block around the command after the `&&`, which means that the the `&` only backgrounds this part.

There is more about using `{ }` for this purpose in the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#CODEBLOCKREF).